# How run two functions on onchange radio in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some selects and inputs on my page:

```
<select class="form-control" id="id_type" name="type" onchange="filterUser(this.value)">
    <option value="">Choose payment</option>
    <?php
    for($i=0;$i<count($types);$i++){
        if($t==$types[$i]['title_type']){
            echo '<option selected  value="'.$types[$i]['id'].'" >' . $types[$i]['title_type'] . '</option>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<option value="'.$types[$i]['id'].'" >' . $types[$i]['title_type'] . '</option>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
<br>

<br><input type="radio" name="del" id="del" value="del" onchange="filterUser(this.value)">Delete<br>
```

When I click on #del I run ajax function. But also I must change my selects values to default. 
How can I after ajax function do other code:

```
$("#formEmpl select").val("");
$("#formEmpl #num_records").val(20);
```

This code must run only for input with id #del, not for all inputs
But ajax called for all inputs

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the event attribute from your radio element and add this at the end of your body:

```
<script>
    $("#del").on("change", function() {
        filterUser(this.value);
        $("#formEmpl select").val("");
        $("#num_records").val(20);
    });
</script>
```

Avoid using `onchange` attribute or any other inline event attribute in your html, [check this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript#Separation_of_behavior_from_markup).